# Как залогировать Exception возникший в close() при использовании try-with-resource

Tags: java, исключения

Я вижу одно решение, не использовать `try-with-resource`, писать `finally` вручную и там логировать.

Можно, конечно, в `catch` получить `getSuppressed()` у нашего первого `Exception` возникшего в `try`, но это сработает только когда этот exception возникнет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class MainTest {
    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
        try (MyCloseable my = new MyCloseable()) {
            // Полезный код
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Catched exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private static class MyCloseable implements Closeable {
        @Override
        public void close() throws IOException {
            throw new IOException("Oops!");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Во первых, `try-with-resource` поддерживает блок `catch`. В нём вполне можно логировать исключения. Особенно, если перехватывать не базовый `Exception`, а его специализированных потомков.

> это сработает только когда этот exception возникнет.

Любой обработчик исключений сработает только когда возникнет исключение. Иначе это уже не обработчик исключений.

Comment: Можно пример кода как мы в блоке catch можем залогировать exception возникший в блоке finally. То есть в try у нас код выполнился без ошибок,а в finally возник exception